# : Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()'

Tags: java, android

I don't know what to do, please help

> 'E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.is2all.so2al_ijaba, PID: 13051
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.is2all.so2al_ijaba/com.is2all.so2al_ijaba.windows_asila}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.is2all.so2al_ijaba.windows_asila.table(windows_asila.java:204)
>                         at com.is2all.so2al_ijaba.windows_asila.onResume(windows_asila.java:439)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6312)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)'

the code :

```
public void table() {

        handler.removeCallbacks(run);
        count=30 ;
        rnd = rand.nextInt(mDataList.size());
        id = mDataList.get(rnd).ID ;
        btn.setText(mDataList.get(rnd).Question);
        btn2.setText(mDataList.get(rnd).Answer_1);
        btn3.setText(mDataList.get(rnd).Answer_2);
        btn4.setText(mDataList.get(rnd).Answer_3);
        btn5.setText(mDataList.get(rnd).Answer_4);
        count_b = mDataList.get(rnd).ID_answer;
        timer();
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() & rnd == 2 || rnd == 4 || rnd == 8 || rnd ==16 || rnd == 32 || rnd == 64 || rnd == 128 ) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(run);
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        table();

        SharedPreferences savechange =  this.getSharedPreferences
            ("savechange", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int Point = savechange.getInt("Point",point);
        this.point = Point;
        btn7.setText("+نقط : "+point);
    }
```

Comment: The error results from mDataList being null.  Where was it initialized?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your "mDataList" is null, so when you call 
`rnd = rand.nextInt(mDataList.size());`

it is giving you the error.

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: Where are you setting the list data?  It sounds like most likely when you are trying to set the list data, it isn't actually getting set

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is stated in your log . Your `mDataList` is null when your activity returns from  background and resumes (as it seems) and you attempt to call mDataList.size() on a null object reference

You can always add check to prevent your app from crashing

```
if(mDataList != null) {
   rnd = rand.nextInt(mDataList.size());
}
```

Maybe you initialize mDataList in onCreate and when your app returns from background it just goes directly to onResume or maybe you don't initialize it at all

Comment: it steel doesn't work